# Netbeans 8.2 will not open on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, ide

recently I have been trying to run the Netbeans IDE on Mac OS X El Capitan on a 13 in MacBook Pro (2015). However, while the program launches with no visible error output, whenever I attempt to create a new project or access a project, no directory structure shows up on the left, and no window is opened.

Here is the output from `java --version` in the terminal, in case this helps.

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans requires JDK 8, as [described in the release notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html#req_sw).